# Raster values in ArcMap need to be fixed for prediction maps

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, r, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I am working on ArcMap with RGB rasters. The rasters have high values and i do not know how to fix it.

When i import them into R, it makes my prediction maps off. I have resampled them to another raster so they are in the same coordinate system and same pixel size.

[image: green raster information in ArcMap]

[image: In r, this is what the raster looks like and shows high values as well. I need help with fixing this in ArcMap]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the NoData value is not recognized when you are importing the data into R. You can check with this command:
`NAvalue(green.3)`

If it does not return 65535 as the NA value then you can set it and try plotting again:
`NAvalue(green.3) <- 65535`

Are these supposed to be an 8 bit RGB? If so, the only values it would be using are 0-255 so those are probably still in the data but not showing up when you plot the layer due to the large default NoData value in the 16 bit data type.

Comment: They are a 16 bit with raster values 0-255.

Comment: I tried that code and it says error. > NAValue(green.3)
Error in NAValue(green.3) : could not find function "NAValue"
> NAValue(green.3) <- 65535
Error in NAValue(green.3) <- 65535 : could not find function "NAValue<-"

Comment: If i could get the values to be between 0-255 on r, that would be great but I am stuck on this now.

Comment: I had a typo in the NAvalue function call, it should be a lower case v. That's also assuming that you are using the raster package. Since the source of these is an 8 bit color depth, storing them in a 16 bit raster data type is unnecessary.

Comment: It could be that you are not running a version of raster that has the `raster::NAvalue` method available or a call error but, it is not necessary as, you can use `x[x > 255] <- NA` to set your NA values.

Comment: > NAvalue(green.3)
[1] -Inf
> NAvalue(green.3) <- 65535
> x[x > 255] <- NA
Error in x[x > 255] <- NA : object 'x' not found

Comment: @Matthew_f that would be because your raster is not named x, this is standard notation used in examples where x denotes any raster with the intent of you plugging in your own data.